# slideshow_view: how to rewrite the output?

Tags: 7, views, navigation

I have a content-type "gallery " which is composed of:

- Field Image
- Field Link (which is an EXTERNAL link like www.google.com or http://exemple.org)

so i've created a view with the link field hidden(the widget of the link field is: "Title, as Link (default)") and the image field

how should I rewrite the output of the image field to put the external link into the image?

i've tried with this: 
    `<a href="[view_node]">[field_image_1]</a>` but this is not working

Comment: If someone is stucked with the same problem:

Follow the answer of Gladiator and the widget of the link must be "URL, plain text" otherwise it will not work.

Thanks again to Gladiator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method : 1

> 1. Place the link above the image field in the views.
> 2. Exclude it from display
> 3. Now rewrite the results of the image
> 4. a href="[field_link]" image field
> 5. This will create the link to the image, so when clicking it will lead the page.

Method :2

> 1. Place the link above the image field in the views.
> 2. Exclude it from display
> 3. Select "output this field as link"
> 4. Click the replacement pattern here, and use the link in the text field
> 5. This will create the link to the image, so when clicking it will lead the
>      page.

Comment: I am unable to use proper a tag here, but you use them properly in views.

Comment: nice hint!!!!!!